# FileNet 5.2 subscription run as user

Tags: filenet-p8

IBM Knowledge Center states that

> Server disables security access checks during subscription execution

but does not mention the user credentials the code uses to execute which you need to know in order to map user RunAs roles on the application server.
What user credentials does FileNet use to execute event action code?

Comment: Either this is just wrong or IBM Knowledge Center has a different understanding of "disables security access" than I do. Try it out yourself, remove a user from the security group of the subscription or document class involved and then all actions that trigger the subscription will fail for this user.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, when you create async subscription it will be executed under p8boostrap user.

And it will keep user context when you execute syncronious subscription.

But you can check it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is using the user who triggered the action. E.g. if a user changes a property of a document (let's say DocumentTitle because it is always there) and clicks save, then an update event will be triggered which launches the subscription (if subscribed to the update event) which launches the action. Use synchronous for short running tasks, you can immediately show the update to the user. With asynchronous the user will have to click "Refresh".

Security can be a pain if not planned carefully at the beginning, for the action to be executed, the user has to have rights for the subscription, action event, document class etc. basically for everything involved or the user will get a cryptic error message when trying to modify the DocumentTitle.

Source: personal experience, sorry no official reference, if in doubt verify first.

Comment: Synchronous subscriptions do run as the user who initiated them, as I have learned, and async subscriptions use one of the admin accounts - but which one? Where is it mapped?

Comment: @RobertMugattarov interesting, somehow I thought it never took the admin, but can't verify at the moment. Must be the original GCD admin I guess.

Comment: @maraca actually, i suppose that it will be bootstrap account, not Domain Admin, cause of you don't provide any passwords for Domain Admin in configurations, you only provide p8ldap - account, for access to LDAP service and p8bootstrap. And when FileNet starts it authenticates in LDAP directory as p8bootstrap account.

Comment: @swepss That would explain my observations right? So you say it takes the user account for both  (or is this bootstrap account something else, just the same in our environments) ?